# Laravel multiple delete checkbox?

Tags: laravel, checkbox

**I want to delete only checked tasks. At the moment I have this:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/destroy">
@foreach($tasks as $t)
<label>            
<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="$t->id">                    
</label> 
  @endforeach  
<button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

**This is my Controller**

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'checked' => 'required',
        ]);

        $checked = $request->input('checked');

        Task::destroy($checked);
    }
```

**And this is my route**

```
Route::post('/destroy', [
    'uses' => 'Controller@destroy',
]);
```

**I don't get no error but the system does not work**

Comment: Can you post your request and response

Comment: Show us the content of `$checked`.

Comment: print the request data and check weather data is posted or not ?? `echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->all()); die;`

Comment: I fixed the problem! Thanks for your support!

The problem was that my id variable was a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem! Thanks for your support!

The problem was that my id variable was a hash.